# Html css dropdown submenu

Tags: html, css, search, dropdown, submenu

i am trying to design this search box filter using html & css. I tried many times but it is not look same as xd design. please help me to design this using html css.

[search box dropdown filter - xd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTs0Q.png)

[design i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtPCk.png)

```css
.wrapper{
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .wrapper .search box{
    width: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -10px #b3c6ff;
  }
  

  .wrapper .search box .dropdown{
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 2px solid #dde2f1;
    color: #9fa3b1;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

  }
  
  .wrapper .search box .dropdown .default option{
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-size: 10px;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search box .dropdown ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 6px -10px #b3ffbd;
    font-style: none;
    color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  #menu{
    background: #fff;
  }

  #moveul{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 220px;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul.active{
    display: block;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    user-select: none; 
    list-style: none;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:last-child{
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li a{
   color: #000;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li ul{
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-style: none;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }


  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li ul li a{
    align-items: center;
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:hover{
    color: #6f768d;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .dropdown:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    border: 8px solid;
    border-color: #5078ef transparent transparent transparent;
  }

  .wrapper .search_box .search_field{
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .search_field .input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: #6f768d;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .wrapper .search_box .search_field .fas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #5078ef;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
      <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="search_box">

        <div class="dropdown">

          <option value="" class="default_option">All Categories
          </option> 

          <ul id="menu">

            <li><a href="">Graphic Design</a>

              <ul id="moveul">

                <li><a href="">Graphic Design</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>

              </ul>

          </li>

            <li><a href="">App Development</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Data Analyst</a></li>

            <li><a href="">Data Research</a></li>

          </ul>

      </div>

        <div class="search_field">

 <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search Your Items Here">

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

i am trying to design this search box filter using html & css. I tried many times but it is not look same as xd design. please help me to design this using html css.

Comment: Please add the code that you tried.

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: I can't write the whole code for you at the moment. But. I highly suggest you try using ```CSS flexbox``` property to match the implementation with your design. Learn more about flex from here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp